# Detecting Firefox Australis from CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

Since Firefox Australis is now on Nightly channel, I want to make my addon compatible with this new UI. I was wondering how I can detect if user is on Firefox Australis from both CSS and JavaScript. For CSS part I am interested to optimize my toolbar icon such that it is compatible with older versions of Firefox as well.

Comment: According to [Draft: Australis and add-on compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/australis-add-on-compat-draft) the toolbar icons are now 18px in the navigation toolbar and 32px in the menu panel and palette. But in the draft there is no CSS selector to detect Australis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From (privileged) JavaScript

```
if("gCustomizeMode" in window){
  //Australis code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you are trying to do. If the user agent has Firefox/28 add the class 'firefox-australis' to the body. Then you can target that class in CSS.

```
<script>
var is_australis = false;
// if the user agent contains Firefox/28, we can assume it's australis
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\/28/)){
    var version = parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\/([0-9]*)/)[1]);
    // should be self-explanatory
    if(version < 28){ return; }
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
    ,   classes = body.getAttribute('class');

    // add the class 'firefox-australis' to the body tag
    body.setAttribute('class', ' firefox-australis');
    // save for reference in JS
    is_australis = true;
}
</script>
<style>
/* Target Australis */
body.firefox-australis{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, For CSS part I want to modify my extension's toolbar button. I believe this method doesn't work for this particular case.

Comment: You'll probably want to detect Firefox 28 or greater unless we're gambling on them removing Australis in 29...

Comment: @Belaviyo according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Toolbars/Creating_toolbar_buttons you can use this method (read the "Styling the button" section)

Comment: @RobM. I still need a selector. Something sensitive to Firefox version (`@media` perhaps). I don't think it would be a good idea to attach a new class to all new browser windows.

Comment: @Belaviyo Fair enough, I wasn't really thinking about this from the perspective of developing an add-on; sorry about that.

Comment: Out of curiosity though, don't you have a parent XUL element that you could assign the class to rather than the body? I'm pretty sure FF allows you to target XUL elements in a DOM like manner.

Answer (score 0):

Run in the Chrome context

```
if(document.querySelector("#PanelUI-popup")){
  //Australis code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

    //Element to style

}
```